# Rails includes for self-referential associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, self-reference

I have these tables:

Category: id, name, parent_id

CategoryImage: id, url, category_id

CategoryImageHistory: id, user_id, category_image_id

parent_id of Category is a foreign key to another Category record (self referential)

I would like to load all Categories, ordered from top level to child as well as their images and image history:

```
Category.where(parent_id: nil)
  .includes(category_image: :category_image_history, children: [category_image: :category_image_history])
```

this will yield these SQL statements:

```
SELECT categories.* FROM categories WHERE parent_id is NULL
SELECT category_images.* FROM category_images WHERE category_images.category_id IN (..)
SELECT category_image_histories.* FROM category_image_histories WHERE category_image_histories.category_image_id IN (..)
SELECT categories.* FROM categories WHERE categories.parent_id IN (..)
SELECT category_images.* FROM category_images WHERE category_images.category_id IN (..)
SELECT category_image_histories.* FROM category_image_histories WHERE category_image_histories.category_image_id IN (..)
```

The category_images and category_image_histories query repeated as first, we search the top level categories then search those category images then histories, then children and then category images then histories.

Is there a Rails way to optimize this? A way to make it search by categories, categories children, then all images and image histories but still make the result line up nicely. Right now this code returns an array of top level categories and each category will respond to .children, .category_images, .category_image_histories correctly.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand exactly what order you wanna have in your result. I assume you want to have an order like:
parent_1, child_1_parent_1, child_2_parent_1, parent_2, child_1_parent_2,...

AND

I assume you have not a child that has a `parent_id` present:

```rb
Category.left_joins(:children).order('NVL(children_categories.id, categories.id), categories.id DESC')
.includes(category_image: :category_image_history)
```

Please check if `children_categories` is the correct name for the association. I am not a 100 percent sure of that